# Preorder traversal in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I was trying to brush up my algorithms skills.
So, preorder traversal of btree:
Here is my attempt.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def preorder(node):
    if not node: return None
    print node.val
    preorder(node.left)
    preorder(node.right)


root = Node(20)
root.left = Node(8)
root.right = Node(22)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(12)
root.left.right.left = Node(10)
root.left.right.right = Node(14)
tree ="""
     20
   8    22
 4  12 10  14
"""
print tree
preorder(root)

20
8
4
12
10
14
22
```

But this is wrong.. as 22 should come after 12.. right?

Comment: Your assignments don't create the tree in your literal string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `Node` assignments -

```
root = Node(20)
root.left = Node(8)
root.right = Node(22)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(12)
root.left.right.left = Node(10)
root.left.right.right = Node(14)
```

The Tree this creates looks like -

```
       20
    8      22
 4    12
   10     14
```

For this, the pre-order traversal you get is correct.

---

For the tree you want -

```
     20
   8    22
 4  12 10  14
```

you should assign `10` and `14` to `root.right.left` and `root.right.right` , not `root.left.right.left` , etc. Example -

```
root = Node(20)
root.left = Node(8)
root.right = Node(22)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(12)
root.right.left = Node(10)
root.right.right = Node(14)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tree that you are forming is not the one that you represented in the code .
And your python method is working correctly , as per the input given to it .

```
def preorder(node):
if not node: return None
print node.val
preorder(node.left)
preorder(node.right)
```

As per the tree that you are creating , everything is getting created in the left subtree , rather than creating a balanced tree .